# Windows Phone 7 browser control with additional script running in browser

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am developing a windows phone application in visual studio (Silverlight in C#) and I added a browser control to the application that i develop to show some random website.

Now i need to run a javascript along with that page in the browser control. How do i add the script to that. is there anyway to append the script directly when the html loads?

The script can be loaded from remote server or from the application itself. Its just to modify the pages a bit and display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the NavigateTo(URI) method of the WebBrowserControl directly with the URL, you can get the source of the HTML page as a string, modify it by injecting your javascript and use the NavigateToString(string html) method to display the content.

Comment: this might be a noob question... how can i get the source of HTML page as a string..